# How to apply indentations settings for comment line (IntelliJ IDEA / Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

I certainly know how to use the line comment shortcut, `ctrl` + `/`, but for some reason the comment starts at the end of line.

If I start with this code:

```
if (something) {
    return 5;
}
```

And use the shortcut from IntelliJ, I end up with:

```
if (something) {
//    return 5;
}
```

But I expect things to look like this:

```
if (something)
    // return 5;
}
```

Is there any way to configure this in IntelliJ? I tried changing the code syntax rules for my target language, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting can be changed in `(Settings / Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Code Generation)`

Options:

- `Line comment at first column.`
- `Block comment at first column.`

It should work both for Android Studio and IntelliJ IDEA.